# visual studio code debug C request timeout

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am testing the debug function of VS code.
Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int d=100;
int x=200;
int main() 
{  
    printf("d=%d,x=%d\n",d,x);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my launch.json in .vscode:

```
        {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
  }
```

I pressed F5 and waited for a really long time, but it didn't respond and
stay on this state:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB8Vo.png)

And after a long time, a dialog box will show up saying "Request time out".

The debug function worked pretty work on my machine before. But I don't know why it doesn't work now.
So anyone tell me what's the problem here?

PS: I have installed the C/C++ extension and opened the "-g" flag when compiling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, just change "externalConsole" in launch.json from true to false, although I don't know why. I'd like it if someone can explain it.